# I need help to create a new TKinter window instead of extending the current one

Tags: python, tkinter, time

This is the code for a maths challenge I wanted to try and make which asked as many questions as you want
but it keeps extending the window instead of creating a new one, which also doesn't update the scorestr.

Any help on how to get it to "dissolve" the current canvas and then close and reopen an updated one with a new question and updated score?

Also if anyone knows how to put a 60 second timer in this it would help me out alot.

Image shows the issue I'm having.

***PLEASE NOTE***
Only refer to the plus section after converting the integers to the string, the other sections haven't been updated as the plus still isn't working.

```
# generate random integer values
from random import randint
import tkinter as tk

score = 0

scorestr = ""

root = tk.Tk()


def game():

    for x in range(3):

        def f():
            global score
            score += 1
        for _ in range(1):
            symbol = randint(0, 0)

        # define symbol for equation

        if symbol == 0:
            maths = "plus"
            value1 = randint(0, 100)
            value2 = randint(0, 100)

        if symbol == 1:
            maths = "minus"
            value1 = randint(0, 100)
            value2 = randint(0, 100)

        if symbol == 2:
            maths = "times"
            value1 = randint(0, 12)
            value2 = randint(0, 12)

        if symbol == 3:
            maths = "divide"
            value1 = randint(1, 12)
            value2 = randint(1, 12)

        # generate some integers

        if value1 < value2:
            temp = value1
            value1 = value2
            value2 = temp
            temp == ""

        value1Str = str(value1)
        value2Str = str(value2)

        if maths == "plus":
            answer = value1 + value2

            canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300)
            canvas1.pack()

            entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

            def clickme():
                uanswer = entry1.get()
                uanswerint = int(uanswer)
                if uanswerint == answer:
                    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Correct')
                    canvas1.create_window(200, 280, window=label3)
                    f()
                    scorestr = str(score)
                else:
                    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Incorrect')
                    canvas1.create_window(200, 280, window=label3)
                root.after(1000, game)


            label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Score: " + scorestr)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)

            label2 = tk.Label(root, text='What is ' + value1Str + ' + ' + value2Str)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=label2)

            button1 = tk.Button(text='Check Answer!', command=clickme)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

        if maths == "minus":
            answer = value1 - value2

            canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300)
            canvas1.pack()

            entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

            def clickme():
                uanswer = entry1.get()
                uanswerint = int(uanswer)
                if uanswerint == answer:
                    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Correct')
                    canvas1.create_window(200, 280, window=label3)

                else:
                    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Incorrect')
                    canvas1.create_window(200, 280, window=label3)
                quit()

            label1 = tk.Label(root, text=answer)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)

            label2 = tk.Label(root, text='What is ' + value1Str + ' - ' + value2Str)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=label2)

            button1 = tk.Button(text='Check Answer!', command=clickme)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

        if maths == "times":
            answer = value1 * value2

            canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300)
            canvas1.pack()

            entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

            def clickme():
                uanswer = entry1.get()
                uanswerint = int(uanswer)
                if uanswerint == answer:
                    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Correct')
                    canvas1.create_window(200, 280, window=label3)

                else:
                    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Incorrect')
                    canvas1.create_window(200, 280, window=label3)
                quit()

            label1 = tk.Label(root, text=answer)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)

            label2 = tk.Label(root, text='What is ' + value1Str + ' * ' + value2Str)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=label2)

            button1 = tk.Button(text='Check Answer!', command=clickme)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

        if maths == "divide":
            answer = value1 / value2

            canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300)
            canvas1.pack()

            entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

            def clickme():
                uanswer = entry1.get()
                uanswerint = int(uanswer)
                if uanswerint == answer:
                    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Correct')
                    canvas1.create_window(200, 280, window=label3)

                else:
                    label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Incorrect')
                    canvas1.create_window(200, 280, window=label3)
                quit()

            label1 = tk.Label(root, text=answer)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)

            label2 = tk.Label(root, text='What is ' + value1Str + ' / ' + value2Str)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=label2)

            button1 = tk.Button(text='Check Answer!', command=clickme)
            canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

        root.mainloop()

game()


print (score)
```

[Window Extending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEoki.png)

Comment: It is because you created new canvas whenever `game()` is executed.  You should create the canvas outside `game()` and using `canvas1.delete("all")` to clear the canvas in each call.  Also the for loop is not necessary at all.  Final move `root.mainloop()` after first call of `game()`.

Comment: Please reduce this code down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

So, if you wanna add a new window while the old window is also open, then you must use the TopLevel window in Tkinter.
`Top1 = tk.Toplevel(root)`
It should open a new window.

But, if you wanna delete the root window and create a new window, you must use
`root.destroy()` To close any root window. Do this inside the function of the button

`root = tk.Tk()` To open the window again.

You will have to add the canvas and other widgets again to update. Or you may simply use while loop to get it

Comment: For your second point, it is much better to reuse the window instead of destroying the old one and creating a new one. Also you said that in order to have 2 windows you *must* use `tk.Toplevel(...)` but technically that is incorrect.